# Path tracer not showing shadows

Tags: c++, rendering, shader, shadow, raytracing

I am trying to implement for research purposes a gradient-domain path tracer. In order to achieve this step I first need a working Path tracer. I have been creating one so far but results are wrong and I will explain you why. Some concepts:

I am working on paths that are generated before sampling them. I mean that the first step of my algorithm consists in calculating a path for a certain pixel (x,y). This path will perform some bounces within the scene and, if terminates on the light, will be considered valid.

First of all: the following is the definition of a struct (will be declared and initialized later), containing some scene info needed to cast ray from the camera into the scene.

```
struct RenderData
{
    vec3 E;
    vec3 p1;
    vec3 dx;
    vec3 dy;
};
```

It is initialized in the InitializeScene method:

```
void InitializeScene(){ // setup virtual screen plane
  vec3 E( 2, 8, -26 ); //Eye position
  vec3 V( 0, 0, 1 ); //LookAt vector
  float d = 0.5f, ratio = SCRWIDTH / SCRHEIGHT, focal = 18.0f;
  vec3 p1(E + V * focal + vec3(-d * ratio * focal, d * focal, 0)); // top-left screen corner in SCREEN SPACE
  vec3 p2(E + V * focal + vec3(d * ratio * focal, d * focal, 0)); // top-right screen corner
  vec3 p3(E + V * focal + vec3(-d * ratio * focal, -d * focal, 0)); // bottom-left screen corner
  mat4 M = rotate( mat4( 1 ), r, vec3( 0, 1, 0 ) );
  p1 = vec3(M * vec4(p1, 1.0f)); //rotating the above points
  p2 = vec3(M * vec4(p2, 1.0f));
  p3 = vec3(M * vec4(p3, 1.0f));
  renderData.dx = (p2 - p1) / (float)SCRWIDTH;
  renderData.dy = (p3 - p1) / (float)SCRHEIGHT;
  renderData.E = vec3(M * vec4(E, 1.0f));
  renderData.p1 = p1;
}
```

The code above is to make you understand how I initialized the scene.
I also have structs to store informations about my paths:

```
struct PathVert {
   vec3 p; vec3 n; //hit point and normal of the surface hit 
};

struct Path {
   PathVert verts[MAX_DEPTH]; //maxDepth is 15 for now
   int vertCount;
   int x, y; //which pixel this path is referring to
};
```

therefore I start consider pixel after pixel.

```
for (int y = 0; y < SCRHEIGHT; y++) for (int x = 0; x < SCRWIDTH; x++)
{     
   Path path;
   if(generatePath(x,y, path)){
      Sample(path);
   }
}
```

The **generatePath()** method indeed tracks the path into the scene and checks all the vertices it hits. The **checkIfRayIntersectSomething(t)** method you will see used, it's just a pseudo method implemented in my framework and that I omit posting cause of its length. I use it to check if my ray hits something in the scene, if it does, it update the "t" with the distance to that object. NOTE: the light is not considered an object itself. Hence, I also have a **checkRayLightIntersection(hitLightPoint)** which checks the intersection with the light, if there is any, the hitLightPoint is updated with the point on the light I have been hitting.
The light is a 2D surface.

```
Vec lightPos = Vec(5, 15, 2); //hard coded position of the light
```

And the light, as said, is a surface, but exactly a square surface, whose 4 angles are:

```
Vec P1 = Vec(lightPos.x - 20, lightPos.y, lightPos.z + 20);
Vec P2 = Vec(lightPos.x + 20, lightPos.y, lightPos.z + 20);
Vec P3 = Vec(lightPos.x + 20, lightPos.y, lightPos.z - 20);
Vec P4 = Vec(lightPos.x - 20, lightPos.y, lightPos.z - 20);
```

Quite big, I know, so the first question relies on this aspect, is it correct having such a big light?

But let's go to the main methods. Hereby you can see the GeneratePath method:

```
bool GeneratePath(int x, int y, Path &path){
   path.x = x;
   path.y = y;
   path.vertCount = 0;

   vec3 P = renderData.p1 + renderData.dx * ((float)(x) + Rand(1)) +  renderData.dy * ((float)(y) + Rand(1));
   vec3 O = renderData.E + vec3(Rand(0.4f) - 0.2f, Rand(0.4f) - 0.2f, Rand(0.4f) - 0.2f);
   vec3 D = normalize(P - O); //direction of the first ray, the one from the camera towards the pixel we are considering

   for (int depth = 1; depth <= MAXDEPTH; depth++){
    float t;
    Vec hitLightPoint;
    PathVert vert;
    if (!checkIfRayIntersectSomething(t)){
        //we didn't find any object.. but we still may have found the light which is an object non represented in the scene
        //the depth check avoids me rendering the light as a white plane
        if (depth > 1 && checkRayLightIntersection(O, D, hitLightPoint)){
            //update the vertex since we realized it's the light
            vert.p = hitLightPoint;
            vert.n = Vec(0, -1, 0);//cause the light is pointing down
            path.verts[depth - 1] = vert;
            path.vertCount++;
            return true; //light hit, path completed    
        }
        return false; //nothing hit, path non valid
    }
    //otherwise I got a hit into the scene
    vert.p = O + D * t; //reach the hitPoint
    vert.n = methodToFindTheNormal();
    vert.color = CalculateColor(vert.p); //according to the material properties (only diffuse objects so far)
    path.verts[depth - 1] = vert;
    path.vertCount++;

    //since I have the light, and a path terminates when it hits the light, I have to check out also if my ray hits this light,
    //and if does, I have to check whether it first hits the light or the object just calculated above
    //moreover with the "depth > 1" check, I avoid again rendering the light which otherwise would be visible as a white plane

    if (depth > 1 && checkRayLightIntersection(O, D, hitLightPoint)){
        float distFromObj = length(vert.p);
        float distFromLight = length(hitLightPoint);
        if (distFromLight < distFromObj){
            //update the vertex since we realized it's the light
            vert.p = hitLightPoint;
            vert.n = Vec(0, -1, 0);
            vert.color = Vec(1, 1, 1);// TODO light color? or light emission?

            path.verts[depth - 1] = vert;
            return true; //light hit, path completed
        }
    }
    if (depth == MAXDEPTH) return false;
       Vec newDir = BSDFDiffuseReflectionCosineWeighted(vert.n, D);//explained later
       D = newDir;
       O = vert.p;
   }
   return false;
}
```

The BSDFDiffuseReflectionCosineWeighted() just calculate the new directions, tested and working. What remains last is the Sample method which calculates the final color of the pixel.

```
Vec Sampling(Path &path){

   Vec color(1, 1, 1);

   for (int vert = 0; vert < path.vertCount - 1; vert++) { //considers the last vertex as the light
      const PathVert &currVert = path.verts[vert];
      const PathVert &nextVert = path.verts[vert + 1];
      Vec wo = (nextVert.p - currVert.p).norm();
      double cosTheta = fabs(wo.dot(currVert.n));
      float PDF = cosTheta/PI;
      if (cosTheta <= 1e-6) return Vec();
      //considering only DIFFUSE objects
      color = color.mult(currVert.color * (cosTheta / M_PI) / PDF);
   }
   return color.mult(Vec(10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f)); //multiplication for the light emission?
}
```

Result with 16SPP is:

[image]

As you can see the results are not that bad but there is one main problem: shadows are missing.. tried many combinations but no improvements. There is some error in the algorithm itself. Can you help me understanding why? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: this is my target reference:

[image]

Comment: Which shadows are missing? Do you have a reference image that's your "target render"?

Comment: @molbdnilo edited the description with a target reference image

Comment: For every Ray from the Camera that hits an object, you have to pass a ray from the hitpoint to all the lights in the scene. The brightness on the point is decided by the ratio of rays that is occluded from the light.

Comment: @codetiger that's called *next event estimation* and it's used to reduce variance. Shadows should appear without that.

Comment: My understanding, if you are doing a photon mapping (Rays start from light and reach camera), then you don't have to calculate shadows separately. If you are doing a usual Ray tracing (Rays start from camera) then you have to calculate shadows using shadow rays (Ray starts from hitpoint to light to see if there is any other object occluding)

Comment: @codetiger I am not doing a photon mapping. I am doing a path tracer and indeed I shouldn't calculate shadows separately, shadows are parth of the global illumination rendering.. part of the light transport, no need to cast them aside from the normal rays